# All keys on the keyboard only open the shutdown console

Tags: keyboard, shutdown

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 x64 on a ASUS x205ta laptop. I knew before I installed it that I would obviously have to install drivers and stuff to get the audio and wifi etc. to work. But the problem I've run into, and cannot figure out has to do with the keyboard. The problem is that if I press any key on the keyboard all it does is display the console for locking, suspending, restarting, and shutting down the computer. That's all any of the keys do. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: ASUS x205ta has a Bay Trail. The webs say it's better to try 16.10 or, if you're brave enough, the soon to be released 17.04.

Comment: Don't mix things up, how would processor matter in this case?